# Jqgrid implementation in ASP.net MVC code snippet issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I am facing problem while passing the parameter and calling the get method while implementing Jqgrid.

How my application works is, it has set of .htm files, a corresponding java script files. Now i want to implement the jqgrid in one tab. i have added all the necessary functions but my controller method itself not getting called kindly help .

Here is my .htm file

```
<div id="report-tab">
<h2>My Grid Data</h2>
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my report.js file, control comes till init function, but it wont trigger my c# function.
i.e json method.

```
var ReportTab = function () {

    return {
        Init: function () {

           //Control comes till here, but it wont go inside, 
             jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                Url: '/Home/GridData',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['Id', 'Votes', 'Title'],
                colModel: [
          { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Votes', index: 'Votes', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'Id',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
                caption: 'My first grid'
            });
        }); 
        }
    }
} ();
```

Here is my controller function in c#

```
public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            _logger.LogMethodAndType();

            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = 1, // we'll implement later 
                page = page,
                records = 3, // implement later 
                rows = new[]{
                new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"1", "-7", "Is this a good question?"}},
                new {id = 2, cell = new[] {"2", "15", "Is this a blatant ripoff?"}},
                new {id = 3, cell = new[] {"3", "23", "Why is the sky blue?"}}
            }
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() { will be invoked only when DOM is refreshed..try placing your jqgrid code outside document.ready

Comment: @Rajesh, it didnt work, i just commented that part as u suggested, it didnt work. please tell me any alternative way

Comment: Ok one thing I was not able to understand why you are placing your jqgrid initialization code inside a method?Over here var ReportTab = function () {

    return {
        Init: function () { ... DO you want grid to be displayed on particular event? are you able to see grid on screen? ur issue is grid refresh or any error on console?

Comment: Actually i'm new to this asp, here in my project all the pages are implemented like that, so i wanted to implement this also in the similar way. so pls suggest me how to overcome this problem

Comment: No, i m not able to see any grid on my html screen :(

Comment: ok but what is the problem- javascript error on console or unable to refresh the data in jqgrid (Grid is getting rendered properly)Check this link here you can see how to write jqgrid code when its there in a tab http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117687/jqgrid-and-jquery-ui-tabs-showing-grids-expanded-only-on-primary-tab-div

Comment: u getting any error on console?

Comment: @Rajesh, I'm getting no error on Jscript console, i think java script console means in I.E there will be yellow color icon appears that one only right. at extreme left corner.

Comment: @Ok Use firebug to debug if things work in firefox then you can go ahead making your life hell in IE..Why IE :(

Comment: i have added these files redmond theme, jquery.jqGrid.min.js & grid.locale-en.js files, correct na?

Comment: Ok, but pls tell me the files which i have included are right or not?

Comment: refer http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install

Comment: Ok, one moment i will check and tell you. pls u have to save my life now. many thanks

Comment: HI, i m getting error , "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method" :(

Answer (score 0):

try this much to render grid on screen

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                Url: '/Home/GridData',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['Id', 'Votes', 'Title'],
                colModel: [
          { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Votes', index: 'Votes', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'Id',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
                caption: 'My first grid'
            });
        });
```

Grid will render properly if the jquery and jqgrid library is properly imported. Table Id:list should also exist on dom/HTML..
If its not rendered then either you are getting any error on firebug console or the Table container div is hidden

Comment: i'm getting error if i add this code, i just imported everything, i m getting error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method